# vlookup kind of operation between two dataframe of pandas based on a common column id

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, vlookup

I want to do vlookup kind of operation on two data-frame and replace values of some existing column based on operation. 
for e.g.

df1:

```
Source Cell Name  Source WCEL DN
   A                   RNC-306
   B                   RNC-307 
   C                   RNC-308
   A                   RNC-308
   D                   RNC-310
   E                   RNC-311
   E                   RNC-311
   F                   RNC-312
```

df2:

```
 Name             Target WCEL DN
   B                   RNC-206
   A                   RNC-207 
   D                   RNC-208
   A                   RNC-207
   C                   RNC-209
   B                   RNC-206
   A                   RNC-207
   D                   RNC-208
   E                   RNC-210
   F                   RNC-211
   G                   RNC-212 
   H                   RNC-213
```

After merging , i want to update df1 from df2 & output should look like below

output:

df1:

```
Source Cell Name  Source WCEL DN
   A                   RNC-207
   B                   RNC-206 
   C                   RNC-209
   A                   RNC-207
   D                   RNC-208
   E                   RNC-210
   E                   RNC-210
   F                   RNC-211
```

I am very new to python so Kindly help me through this how to resolve & get this output using pandas in python.
Also to note that data is huge & the column name on which merging needs to be done has different name.i.e 'Source Cell Name' in df1 & 'Name' in df2. 
I want to update the column 'Source WCEL DN' of df1 from  column 'Target WCEL DN 'of df2 as we can do it using vlookup in excel simply.

Comment: @jezrael : i cannot do here set_index based on Source Cell Name as data in these column are duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

```
df1.columns = ['Name', 'Source WCEL DN']
df1.merge(df2, on='Name' , how='left', left_index=True, right_index=True).drop('Source WCEL DN', axis=1)
```